# Displaying a file inside iframe gives problem in iPhone

Tags: css, iframe

I wrote a code to display the text file inside  tag.
The display works fine in android devices but in iPhone while I try to scroll down, display moves around sideways too and gets back to the center position as a rubber effect.
Have been trying all possible solutions from previous similar problems but could not get it done.

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog2">
<iframe src="documents/agreement.txt" id="dialogframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#dialog2
{
    position : relative;
    top : 0px;
    width : 100vw;
    max-width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    background-color: white;
    overflow : auto;
    white-space : nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
iframe#dialogframe
{
    top : 0px;
    width : 1px;
    min-width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    border : none;
    left : 0px;
    display : block;
}
```

Comment: Include your code too so community can help you.

Comment: @Abdollah Thank you for the suggestion I just edited my post with the codes.